# Error when running Data Profiling Task with Azure SQL Server data

Tags: azure, ssis, azure-sql-database, azure-sql-server, data-profiling

When running a Data Profiling Task in SSIS with data from an Azure SQL Server, I receive the following error message:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): USE statement is not
> supported to switch between databases. Use a new connection to connect
> to a different database.

I am unsure how to work with this message, since I do not switch between databases. The target of the Data Profiling task is a .txt file.

What am I missing?

## (Hopefully) helpful note:

When I try copying data from the same Azure SQL Server database to a .txt file on my desktop (using a Data Flow Task), everything works fine. Also, when choosing the same connection manager in the Data Profiling Task, the correct tables and views of my database are listed. So I'm sure it's not a connection problem and it may be a Data Profiling Task specific error.

I use Visual Studio 2017 Community Version 15.9.28307.280.